# Is it possible to do in silverlight like in flash: loading a flash movieclip at runtime and remotely?

Tags: silverlight, flash, actionscript

I can't see how to do this because silverlight is compiled.

I don't want to load a video, I want to load a component/object that will be instantiated at runtime. Flash can easily do this as movieclip is also an component/object.

Comment: What do you mean loading a flash movie clip at runtime and remotely? You need to go into more detail.

Comment: Movieclip in flash is not for video, it's a full object component. So I don't want to load a video, I want to load a component/object that will be instantiated at runtime. Flash can easily do this as movieclip is also an component/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, for the nitty gritty details take a look at [Managing Dynamic Content Delivery In Silverlight, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315412.aspx).

For a ready made solution you can look at using MEF to provide the framework for building a dynamically compose-able solution. Take a look [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/PrismTutorial_Part1.aspx) for a quick start.

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted. Seems much more complex than flash though.

Answer (score 0):

What video format are you trying to use? You can certainly load remote video files and play them in Silverlight, but it depends on the format. [This](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/audioandvideo/) article should help you get started.

Comment: I don't want to load a video, I want to load a component.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MefShapes sample from this presentation.  It uses MEF to dynamically load different XAP files.  http://www.bendewey.com/blog/index.php/337/silverlight-using-mef-presentation-at-philly-net-code-camp